# Shopify - auto-tagging by 'compare at price' difference

Tags: shopify

The shopify store I edit has a 'sale' collection. This consists of products which have been auto-tagged on the condition that the 'compare at price' is higher than the actual price.

I want to create a new 'clearance' section, which would consist of products where the actual price is cheaper than the compare at price by 50% or greater. I can't find a simple way to do this (i.e. by using the inbuilt collection creator).

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Discounts are applied at the checkout, not when browsing a product. That is why the Smart Collection logic has no conditions based on discounts. If I were you I would try and work out how to build a collection "clearance" with conditions that make sense, and then you could create a price rule/discount that would apply to that collection (50% off). It seems like that is the way to go.

Comment: I might have used the term 'discount' incorrectly. Products marked with 'sale' have their current price set lower than the 'compare at price' but no generic discount is applied to them. I hadn't thought of a applying a discount to a collection but the price difference varies by product so that wouldn't suit my needs. I have managed to get the product.label to follow the rule of > 50% difference = clearance, < 50% difference = sale, so the banner is different for the user at least. What I really want to link this in with an auto product tag that allows me to create a clearance collection.